# Extending upon a jQuery plugin, without necessarily touching the original plugin code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now I am making use of a great cookie handler I found https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie for jquery. Only problem is, it will only set cookies by days. I would like to be able to bypass that and set them by seconds/hours in some cases, or maybe even to a specific time.

Looking at the plugin I know where I cam make the alterations to it specifically. But I am wondering is there a means of extending the plugin with my own custom code somehow so when I call the plugin like normal I can use parameters I've set. The whole idea is to avoid hacking into the initial script so if the author does release a new version in time I can update it accordingly and not lose any changes I may forget about in the upgrade process.

In the current plugin line 44-47 there is

```
if (typeof options.expires === 'number') {
                var days = options.expires, t = options.expires = new Date();
                t.setDate(t.getDate() + days);
            }
```

which I know I can hack directly into that and do as I want. But the idea again is to do it through some external means using the same script overall

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by others, I think the plugin already supports the functionality you want to add.
But I'm going to answer your question `> I am wondering is there a means of extending the plugin with my own custom code`:

The plugin sets `$.cookie` to a function with three arguments (`function (key, value, options)`). You can extend it this way:

```
// in a js file after including `jquery.cookies.js`
(function () {
    var cookie = $.cookie;
    $.cookie = function (key, value, options) {
        // TODO: add your code here

        $.cookie = cookie;
        var out = $.cookie(key, value, options);
        $.cookie = this;
        return out;
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that assumption is correct.

you can use

```
$.cookie('my-key', 'my-valye', {
    expires: new Date()
})
```

Or

```
var expires = new Date();
expires.setHours(expires.getHours() + 1);
$.cookie('my-key', 'my-valye', {
    expires: expires 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the number of seconds you want by 86400. So for 30 seconds use:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 30/86400, path: '/' });
```

Comment: the current cookie script will take the number given and convert it to days + ie: `t.setDate(t.getDate() + days` so this won't work unfortunately hence the desire to extend it without hacking into ti

Comment: yes I have seen the code. Using a bigger number for example, wouldn't 600 seconds = 0.00694444 days?